# Console Application to count all '#' characters in a text file

Tags: c#

My code is posted below. I expect it to output the number of `#` characters in an input file. It is currently not providing the expected output.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StreamReader oReader;

    if (File.Exists(@"C:\Documents and Settings\9chat73\Desktop\count.txt"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a word to search");
        string cSearforSomething = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
        oReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Documents and Settings\9chat73\Desktop\count.txt");
        string cColl = oReader.ReadToEnd();
        string cCriteria = @"\b" + cSearforSomething + @"\b";
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex oRegex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(cCriteria, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        int count = oRegex.Matches(cColl).Count;
        Console.WriteLine(count.ToString());
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This is giving me output as 0 every time. I have the below file as count.txt :`00100324103| #00100324137| #00100324145| #00100324153| #00100324179|` . I want to calculate the number of Hashes(#) inside the file. How to do that.

Comment: Make sure you really have required words in *count.txt* file. Or if you don't see anything, then make sure this file exists

Comment: I have the below file as count.txt :00100324103|
  #00100324137|
  #00100324145|
  #00100324153|
  #00100324179|

.   I want to calculate the number of Hashes(#) inside the file.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Set some breakpoints and check the values of your variables at each step. Then you can identify where the problem is.  Also, note that StreamReader should be disposed by encapsulating it in a `using` block.

Comment: I just created a dummy text file that just said 'cat' or 'dog' over and over again. It was able to correctly count both words.

Comment: You should consider passing in a file at the command-line. This will allow you to avoid hard coding it.

Comment: I have the below file as count.txt :00100324103| #00100324137| #00100324145| #00100324153| #00100324179| . I want to calculate the number of Hashes(#) inside the file. How to do that. Kindly help me..

Comment: Looking at that, I think that your search criteria is wrong. Why do you append backspace characters to each end of it?

Comment: @SeanCogan - those are not backspace characters, those are word boundaries.  However, they are what are causing the problem, for two reasons.  One, # is a not an "word" character, and Two, the hashes are not standalone characters.  Remove those \b and this will work.

Comment: The problem is that the symbol '#' you are looking for is a special one, and so should be escaped

Comment: @WonkotheSane Oh, thanks for clearing that up! I knew they were the reason for the problem when I tested it on my machine and removed them, but I guess I just didn't realize what they were doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that **'#'** (symbol your looking for) is a *special symbol* in regular expressions
and so, should be *escaped*:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  //String fileName = @"C:\Documents and Settings\9chat73\Desktop\count.txt"; 

  // To search dinamically, just ask for a file:
  Console.WriteLine("Enter a file to search");
  String fileName = Console.ReadLine().Trim(); 

  if (File.Exists(fileName)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a word to search");
    String pattern = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

    // Do not forget to escape the pattern! 
    int count = Regex.Matches(File.ReadAllText(fileName), 
                              Regex.Escape(pattern), 
                              RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Count;

    Console.WriteLine(count.ToString());
  }

  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Hello , I want to select the file dynamically at run time then how can I change in the above code ???

Comment: @Debopam Chatterjee: To select file dynamically, just ask user for a file: see my edit

Comment: Thank You . But I do not want to paste the location in console rather I want to redirect to the file and After selecting the file then it will ask for the # count. Can you please  help on this ?

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for # as separate word. Remove word boundaries requirement from your criteria:

```
string cCriteria = cSearforSomething;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the above

```
int count = cColl.Count(x => x == '#');
```

---

```
var count = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\...").Count(x => x == '#');
```

Comment: where could I place it in the above program ?? int count = cColl.Count(x => x == '#'); ??

Comment: its telling that Error 3 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\Projects\PDA\PDA\Program.cs 15 98 PDA

Comment: int count = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\...").All(x => x == '#').Count();

Comment: There's a drawback in your solution: the code can find single character only, not arbitrary string

Answer (score 0):

```
string cCriteria = @"\b" + cSearforSomething + @"\b";
```

This is your problem. If you remove the @"\b" from each end, you'll get the correct amount of '#' characters, because those characters denote the ends of a word and the '#' character is not it's own word.